# Hash input field data with PHP

Tags: php, forms, hash

I have a hidden input field that needs multiple bits of data pulling into it and hashing with sha256. Each bit of information has to have a string after it to make it unique:

This is what I tried last:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="<?php echo hash("sha256", [$_REQUEST['AMOUNT'],"31232rw",$_REQUEST['CURRENCY'],"31232rw",$_REQUEST['LANGUAGE'],"31232rw"]); ?>"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: The second argument to the `hash()` function should be a string, but you're passing an array, so I guess you're seeing an error?  Maybe you could join your array elements together using `implode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="<?php echo hash("sha256", $_REQUEST['AMOUNT']."31232rw".$_REQUEST['CURRENCY']."31232rw".$_REQUEST['LANGUAGE']."31232rw"); ?>" />
```